# Make CSS Button active when click and change the content of the div.

Tags: html, css

My desired result is to have a menu css buttons, when click it **changes the content** of the div... Of course I manage to do that...
Well here's the problem:
Whenever I click the **2nd** or **3rd** button/link it manages to change the div content but when you started to **click anywhere** in the page it **changes back to its default content**...
**I want to make both button/link and the div content stays active even when I click anywhere in the page.**
I want to achieve this in **Pure CSS only**. I know there is a code for that, though I'm not that good enough to make it happen. Can anyone help me with this problem?

### This is my HTML Code looks like

```html
<div id="mynavtabcontent">

  <a id="video" tabindex="1">Video</a>
  <a id="apps" tabindex="2">Apps</a>
  <a id="music" tabindex="3">Music</a>

 <div id="content">
  <div id="def">Video Content here</div>
  <div id="videocontent">Video Content here</div>
  <div id="appscontent">Apps Content here</div>
  <div id="musiccontent">Music Content here</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

### This is my CSS code

The **#def id is the default content** and **the #videocontent is the mirror of the default** whenever I want to go back to the video div content

```css
#mynavtabcontent{
 font-family: Verdana;
 font-size: 18px;
}
#mynavtabcontent a{
 text-decoration: none;
 padding: 7 7 7 7px;
 background-color: yellow;
 color: #222;
}
#mynavtabcontent a:hover{
 background-color: #333;
 color: white;
 cursor: pointer;
}
#content{
 border:1px dashed black;
 background-color: pink;
 height: 400px;
 width: 200px;
 margin-top: 50px;
}
#videocontent, #appscontent, #musiccontent{
 display: none;
}
#video1:focus~#content div:nth-child(1),
#video:focus~#content div:nth-child(2),
#apps:focus~#content div:nth-child(3),
#music:focus~#content div:nth-child(4){
 display: block;
 
}
#video1:focus~#content #def,
#video:focus~#content #def,
#apps:focus~#content #def,
#music:focus~#content #def{
 display:none;
}
```

### Here is the result

**Run code snippet Click 2nd or 3rd button then click anywhere in the content. To see what I mean** about making it active so it won't go back to the default state when you click anywhere.

```css
#mynavtabcontent{
 font-family: Verdana;
 font-size: 18px;
}
#mynavtabcontent a{
 text-decoration: none;
 padding: 7 7 7 7px;
 background-color: yellow;
 color: #222;
}
#mynavtabcontent a:hover{
 background-color: #333;
 color: white;
 cursor: pointer;
}
#content{
 border:1px dashed black;
 background-color: pink;
 height: 400px;
 width: 200px;
 margin-top: 50px;
}
#videocontent, #appscontent, #musiccontent{
 display: none;
}
#video1:focus~#content div:nth-child(1),
#video:focus~#content div:nth-child(2),
#apps:focus~#content div:nth-child(3),
#music:focus~#content div:nth-child(4){
 display: block;
 
}
#video1:focus~#content #def,
#video:focus~#content #def,
#apps:focus~#content #def,
#music:focus~#content #def{
 display:none;
}
```

```html
<div id="mynavtabcontent">

  <a id="video" tabindex="1">Video</a>
  <a id="apps" tabindex="2">Apps</a>
  <a id="music" tabindex="3">Music</a>

 <div id="content">
  <div id="def">Video Content here</div>
  <div id="videocontent">Video Content here</div>
  <div id="appscontent">Apps Content here</div>
  <div id="musiccontent">Music Content here</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

If there is no other way with CSS... **Can anyone provide me a javascipt code for this?** *It would really help me thanks!* -edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your links looses focus as soon as you click elsewhere. You need to use something that can preserve state - :checked pseudo element is a perfect fit. You could have hidden inputs and manage it states with labels. Here is your code with changes applied to it:

```
<div id="mynavtabcontent">

  <input type="radio" name="content-toggle" id="video"> <label for="video" tabindex="1">Video</label>
  <input type="radio" name="content-toggle" id="apps"> <label for="apps" tabindex="2">Apps</label>
  <input type="radio" name="content-toggle" id="music"> <label for="music" tabindex="3">Music</label>

  <div id="content">
    <div id="def">Video Content here</div>
    <div id="videocontent">Video Content here</div>
    <div id="appscontent">Apps Content here</div>
    <div id="musiccontent">Music Content here</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

and css:

```
#mynavtabcontent input {
  display: none;
}

#mynavtabcontent{
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-size: 18px;
}
#mynavtabcontent label{
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 7 7 7 7px;
  background-color: yellow;
  color: #222;
}
#mynavtabcontent label:hover{
  background-color: #333;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#content{
  border:1px dashed black;
  background-color: pink;
  height: 400px;
  width: 200px;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
#videocontent, #appscontent, #musiccontent{
  display: none;
}
#video1:checked~#content div:nth-child(1),
#video:checked~#content div:nth-child(2),
#apps:checked~#content div:nth-child(3),
#music:checked~#content div:nth-child(4){
  display: block;

}
#video1:checked~#content #def,
#video:checked~#content #def,
#apps:checked~#content #def,
#music:checked~#content #def{
  display:none;
}
```

http://codepen.io/MakiBM/pen/KgXzma

Comment: I will... Thanks =D until I have 15 reputation, I'm new here!

Comment: Aha, ok. Thx in advance and WELCOME! :)

Answer (score 0):

There really anything you can do for CSS as far as actions. CSS is styling only.

You will need to use some javascript to handle the actions.

Javascript interacts with the DOM to make the syntax changes in the browser.

However, you can have limited control with things such as animation using CSS properties such as transition, transform, :hover, :active, :focus, and @key-frames.

Comment: I see so there really is no other way... The reason why I avoid using Java is because I don't how to use it.

Comment: Java and javascript are completly different languages.